# Limit the size of a div between two navbars

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm facing this issue: i'm developing a web app with angular with the css framework bootstrap 4.0.0. This app needs to fit the size of the screen (no scrollbars).

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark">
    Upper navBar    
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand navbar-dark">
    Test
</nav>
```

When I put an image in the template of my route it goes under the bottom navBar and makes the page scrollable.

So i'd like to know how I can limit the height of the content of the router-outlet without writing a fix size in Css to keep it responsive !

Thanks

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANPl.jpg)

Comment: Can we have a fiddle or at least an image?

Comment: What happens if the height of the `router-outlet` exceeds the viewport/browser height. Does just `router-outlet` have a scrollbar but not the entire "app"?

Comment: @ZimSystem the scrollbar is on the entire app

Comment: Then why does it say "This app needs to fit the size of the screen (no scrollbars)."?

Comment: This web app will be used on tablet and we don't want to have any scrollabar. All the content must fit in.

Answer (score 0):

If both navbars have a fixed `height`, you can apply `height: calc(100vh - XXX);` to you content element, where "XXX" stands for the heights of both navbars added together (in px).

(And don't forget to add `margin: 0` to `html, body` to avoid default margins which would cause a scrollbar with the above code)

Comment: It doesn't work. It's quiet weird actually becuse i set the max-height of my router outlet to 50vh just to try and it doesn't change anything (in my router outlet there is juste a <img>).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Bootstrap 4, I'd use flexbox...

https://www.codeply.com/go/bukgbRdpYl

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark">
    Upper navBar
 </nav>
 <router-outlet>
    ..
 </router-outlet>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark">
    Test
 </nav>
</body>
```

You don't really want to have fixed position navbars, otherwise the content will hide behind the navbars. I don't know how you want to handle the scrolling.

Another example: https://www.codeply.com/go/aKhXKOeBTi

Comment: Unfortantly that solution doesn't work on my project even if it works in codeply :'(. About the scrolling, I'll just have images or button or dashboards there no need to scroll. I won't have big texts or long pages

Comment: The concept is still the same